# Cordova 4.0.1 CDV camera <Cordova/NSData+Base64.h> not found

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I just updated my cordova ios version to 4.0.1 and i have started getting error in CDV camera plugin which says   not found does anyone face same issue and what is the resolution

Answer (score 3):

As listed in the Cordova Github page from the Cordova 4.0 `Cordova/NSData+Base64.h` is removed from the Cordova

Reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/API%20changes%20in%204.0.md

As written in github page:

> Plugin authors are encouraged to use the (iOS 7+) base64 encoding and decoding methods available in NSData instead.

So you may change the method in the plugin or can update to the latest latest plug in which don't use that file

If you are going to make change in the plugin other option can be

> Since cordova-ios will only support iOS 7 and up going forward, change your plugin to use NSJSONSerialization instead, it's pretty straightforward.

Ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9638

Comment: FYI using the latest version of this plugin (at 29/7/2016) on phonegap build still gives this error

Answer (score 0):

Remove and Again Add Your Plugin.
My self It's Working.

```
cordova plugin rm "your Plugin name"
cordova plugin add "your Plugin name"
```

Example

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-email
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email
```